# DoubleClick Search user does not have read access

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client, double-click

> Permission denied: the DoubleClick Search user does not have read
>   access to the report scope. [412] Errors [    Message[Permission denied:
>   the DoubleClick Search user does not have read access to the report
>   scope.] Location[If-Match - header] Reason[conditionNotMet]
>   Domain[global] ]

'